# HandsOnTable Dropdown Without Editable Text?

Tags: handsontable

Is it possible to use a `dropdown` column in a HandsOnTable without the editable textbox?

I know you can set the `type` to `dropdown` and it will validate/highlight red when you enter an invalid value, but is there a way to completely disable text entry for `dropdown` columns?  It seems just using the `readOnly` property on the column blocks the `dropdown` altogether.

Comment: It seems like the `select` cell type is something that would fit your needs. Here's the docs with a demo https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/select-cell-type/. It does not show the icon of the arrow though.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the `readOnly` option will disable you dropdown. So I believe the closest solution you can use is the `allowIndvalid = false` (true by default) :

> allowInvalid: true (optional) - allows manual input of value that does not exist in the source. In this case, the field background highlight becomes red and the selection advances to the next cell
>
> allowInvalid: false - does not allow manual input of value that does not exist  in the source. In this case, the ENTER key is ignored and the editor field remains opened.

[Documentation Link](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.5/demo-autocomplete.html#strict)

You can use this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mx6fppf1/) to quickly check this option

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and was able to resolve it with such steps. Maybe this could help:

1 when creating columns add a special className to the necessary column type:

```
{
    data: 'priceUnitsName',
    type: 'dropdown',
    invalidCellClassName: 'colored',
    source: Object.keys(unitNames),
    width: 100,
    className: 'disable-edit',
}
```

2 Subscribe to events to handle cancel editing:

```
private targetCell: HTMLTableCellElement;
public settings: GridSettings = {
    // your settings
    afterOnCellMouseDown: (event: MouseEvent, coords: CellCoords, TD: HTMLTableCellElement) => {
        this.targetCell = TD;
    },
    afterBeginEditing: (row: number, column: number) => {
        if (this.targetCell.classList.contains('disable-edit')) { // this handle only necessary columns with special class
            setTimeout(() => {
                const inputCollection: HTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('handsontableInput');
                Array.from(inputCollection).forEach((input: HTMLTextAreaElement) => {
                    input.blur(); // this calls blur on element manually
                });
            });
        }
    },
```

Maybe this is not the best decision, but by default, handsontable can't make dropdown elements readonly with leaving open-close dropdown functional and I can't find any workable suggestion with this.
Checked on 'dropdown' and 'date' types, and it works.